# Сколько пар «дружных доминошек» можно составить из заданного набора доминошек

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Задача:

Вася нашел в комоде кучу доминошек из разных наборов. Каждая доминошка представляет собой прямоугольник, разделенный на две половинки. На каждой из половинок нарисовано от 0 до 6 точек. Ориентации доминошки не имеют — их можно как угодно поворачивать.

Вася решил называть «дружными доминошками» пару доминошек, которые можно поставить в игре рядом (то есть доминошки в паре соприкасаются половинками с равными числами) в том или ином порядке.

По заданному набору доминошек определите, сколько пар «дружных доминошек» можно составить из него. Пары, отличающиеся хотя бы одной доминошкой, считаются различными. По-разному составленная пара из одних и тех же доминошек считается один раз.

Примеры:

Пример 1
Ввод:

```
2
1 2
2 3
```

Вывод:

```
1
```

Пример 2
Ввод:

```
5
1 2
2 3
3 1
4 3
4 3
```

Вывод:

```
8
```

Я сделал рабочий скрипт, но он не зашёл в чекер, слишком долго работает. Нужно через словари решить как-то. Подскажите, примерно как

Comment: А что делает рабочий скрипт?

Comment: Он каждые 2 цифры (1 доминошка) сравнивает с остальными. Если есть совпадение - прибавляем 1. Полностью работает, пытался сократить, используя словарь, не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Разных костяшек всего 28. Заводим треугольную таблицу, заполняем нулями.

Добавляем домино по одной штуке.

Для кости a|b, где a<=b добавляем к результату сумму строки а, сумму столбца b, и отнимаем значение ячейки a|b
(последнее нужно для отработки условия `По-разному составленная пара из одних и тех же доминошек считается один раз`)

Инкрементируем  ячейку a|b и суммы строки а и столбца b

Comment: Спасибо огромное, попробую сделать

Answer (score 1):

Метод грубой силы: `O(M + N**3)` алгоритм, где `M` — количество домино на входе, а `N=7` для примера с домино:

- если на входе `n` костяшек домино с `a` точек на одной половинке и `b` точек на другой (`a:b` костяшка), то записываем `n` в (a, b) и (b, a) элементы NxN матрицы
- обходим все возможные костяшки i:j такие что `i <= j` (*«ориентации доминошки не имеют»*)

  - если больше одной i:j костяшки (дубликаты), то C(n, 2) уникальных пар получается (количество способов выбрать два предмета из `n` набора), где `n`— количество дубликатов (количество i:j костяшек)
  - каждые `m` домино `k:j` ниже в том же столбце образуют `n x m` пар с текущими i:j домино (`n` костяшек на первом месте, `m` костяшек на втором месте пары). Местами не меняются, так как *«По-разному составленная пара из одних и тех же доминошек считается один раз»*
  - аналогично для строки: каждые `m` домино `i:k` справа в той же строке образуют `n x m` пар. Для диагональных домино (i:i — одинаковые половинки), так как нет разницы при вращении костяшек, то проход по строке пропускается, чтобы дважды не считать одинаковые пары (i:i i:k и i:i k:i).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# read dominoes
N = 7
dominoes = [[0] * N for _ in range(N)]
for _ in range(int(input())):
    i, j = map(int, input().split())
    dominoes[j][i] = dominoes[i][j] = dominoes[i][j] + 1

# count "friendly" pairs
npairs = 0
for i in range(N):  # for each domino i:j where i <= j
    for j in range(i, N):
        n = dominoes[i][j]
        if n:
            npairs += n * (n - 1) // 2   # {n \choose 2} pairs with itself
            for k in range(i+1, N):      # top-down
                npairs += dominoes[k][j] * n
            if i != j:  # don't count twice 
                for k in range(j+1, N):      # left-right
                    npairs += dominoes[i][k] * n

print(npairs)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/zzaJaK).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Всё работает

Comment: @RategThises: если работает, вы можете [отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)